# Implicit methods are not shown in code completion in intelliji idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit, code-completion

```
val intValue = 2
```

intValue.**toBinaryString**

toBinaryString method is not shown in suggestion of intelliji idea, But this has been showing in eclipse

toBinaryString method is present in RichInt class , which means not showing all implicit methods

I feel all implicits methods are not shown, Cam someone suggest how to achieve this

intelliji idea version :2017.2

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: i am mentioning here about scala

Comment: Can your provide a minimal project demonstrating the issue? One possibility I can think of is that your project doesn't have a Scala SDK set. Otherwise you might need to submit a bug report to Jetbrains

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FSCL-12435

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean *toBinaryString* method?

Comment: yeah, i mean the same .... can you please help me out here, I couldn't basically get implicit methods available for a object in intelliji, But in eclipse i could get straight forward just by ctrl+space